# Honoring the date time format string in StringFormatter

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datetime, datetime-format

In XAML I have something like this:

```
Text="{Binding my_date, StringFormat=\{0:ddd M/d/yy\}}"
```

currently it outputs some thing like **Mon 12/23/13**

I want it to honor the region and language settings date time format so if they pick a yy/mm/dd it should show the date in correct format. I know the param "d" should do that, from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

But for some reason when it gets combined with the rest of the formatter as

```
Text="{Binding my_date, StringFormat=\{0:ddd d\}}"
```

Then it doesn't work correctly. What is the correct format I should use in this case?

Comment: Which is the final output you are looking for?

Comment: @FeliceM something like Mon 12/23/13  BUT if user changes their date format to yyyy/MM/dd then the same thing should show as Mon 2013/12/23

Comment: I do not have silverlight installed so I cannot check if there is a masked textbox available for Silverlight but if it is there this could be an option to force the user to write the date always in the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) strings can't be combined into a single string format. This would need to be done in two steps:

```
var weekday = my_date.ToString("ddd");
var day = my_date.ToString("d");
var both = string.Format("{0} {1}", weekday, day);
```

In XAML, this would be more verbose, but the following should work (this is untested):

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="\{0\} \{1\}">
          <Binding Path="my_date" StringFormat="ddd" />
          <Binding Path="my_date" StringFormat="d" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: I don't have multibinding in Silverlight :(

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should write a Converter for it?

Comment: @DevWannaBe Either a converter or just add a readonly `my_date_formatted` property that returns the above.

Comment: Ok thanks, hadn't thought about Properties, will try that too. So is "ddd" also honoring the culture? so it Monday in French is something else, then it would show that?

Comment: @DevWannaBe Yes it does. You can also use a `CultureInfo` for the `provider` parameter of [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want a specific culture.